# NiFi Dynamic Remote URL value

Tags: apache-nifi

I am creating a dataflow that needs to get and process the responses from a dynamic endpoint with a numeric resource id. For example, http://my-rest-service:8080/resource/{id} where {id} ranges from 1 to 100

I was looking into using a Counter but it does not look like I can easily inject the value. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@paolo de roxas,

You can use Looping to inject the values with following reference.

https://gist.github.com/ijokarumawak/01c4fd2d9291d3e74ec424a581659ca8

In that way,you can use InvokeHTTP to change url with respect to id from 1 to 100.

This may helpful for you.